# CORS request made despite error in console

Tags: javascript, cors, google-cloud-storage, fetch-api

I'm fiddling around with Google Cloud Storage. I've created a simple Python Flask handler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import secrets

import flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from google.cloud import storage


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('<my-bucket>')


@app.route('/')
def get_upload_urls():
    blob = bucket.blob('00000' + secrets.token_hex())
    return flask.jsonify({
        'url': blob.create_resumable_upload_session(),
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 9999)
```

This is accompanied by a really simple web frontend:

*index.html*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input id="input" type="file" />
      <button id="button">Upload</button>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*index.js*:

```
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const button = document.getElementById('button')


button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const [ body ] = input.files
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9999')
    const { url } = await response.json()
    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body,
    })
})
```

This frontend allows me to pick a file, and upload it to Google Cloud Storage using a resumable upload session created by the Python backend.

The problem with this is that it actually works. I'd expect the PUT request to fail, but it doesn't.

When a file has been selected and the upload button is pressed, the following errors are logged to the console:

> index.html:1 Failed to load
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b//o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3333' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
index.js:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
  async function (async)
  button.addEventListener @ index.js:5
```

However, the PUT request was made succesfully and the file shows up in the Google Cloud Storage. I can download it and it appears to be totally fine.

Why doesn't the PUT request fail despite the CORS error in the console?

**Edit**:

I'm just looking for an explanation, not for a workaround — I'm going to configure CORS properly anyway. I would just like to know why the request doesn't fail, and why fetch does reject.

Comment: have you tried using mode in fetch `{mode: 'no-cors'}`

Comment: CORS prevents people "borrowing" resources from other origins, what a remote server does with data **sent** to it is clearly in the hands of the server

Comment: The only explanation I can imagine: (1) the server sends back the right CORS headers (including the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header) in response to the OPTIONS preflight the browser (automatically on its own) does before trying your PUT, & then (2) because the preflight succeeds, the browser goes ahead & sends the PUT from your code, & then (3) the server receives the PUT & successfully handles it, but then (4) the response the server sends back for the PUT doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so (5) your browser blocks your frontend code from accessing that response

Comment: You might want to consider updating the question to paste in the details of the requests and responses that show up in the Network pane of your browser devtools when you frontend code runs — including the HTTP status codes for the responses, and all the headers for both the requests and the response. I say *requests* and *responses* plural because, due the fact you’re making a cross-origin PUT request, your browser will definitely be sending a preflight OPTIONS prior to sending your PUT request. So you want to look at the details for the OPTIONS in addition to the details for the PUT

Comment: You are doing _two_ `fetch`es here, right? So presumably the first one (`fetch('http://localhost:9999')`) fails and causes the console entry, and the other one, your actual PUT request, succeeds ...

Answer (score 1):

@sideshowbarker was right, I had the same issue. CORS needs to be set also in PUT response in addition to OPTIONS preflight request. Then `fetch` will succeed (even though upload worked before).